# Merge PDFs, keep TOC and Page Numebring from original PDFs

Tags: pdf, merge

The goal is to merge multiple PDF files. The files already have the right numbering and the first pages have Roman numbering which should be conserved. The files also have PDF-ToC/bookmarks that I would like to conserve.

Using sejda-console I was able to conserve the PDF-ToC/bookmarks but not the page numbering.

Comment: Page numbering cannot be conserved. Hard coded in a PDF just like the other text.